# WooCommerce odd <b> injection before text " proceed to checkout " in button

Tags: woocommerce

I'm seeing an odd injection of a  in the Checkout button on the Cart Page that's adding space ove the button text and I cannot for the life of me find out what's causing it.

Here's the HTML

```
<p><a href="https://xxxxxx.com/shop/checkout/" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward"><br>
    Proceed to checkout</a>
    </p>
```

[image]

Checked funtions.php and all styles...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but you could change the inline property to grid...

```
.checkout-button.button.alt.wc-forward {
display: grid;
}
```

**Before:**
[image]

**After**
[image]